# Array contains doesn't capture

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a array and array looks like this,I want to know about the is NewsType ="Int" included in the array.

array is NewsTypeArray.

When i debug in firebug.array looks like this,

```
0 Object { NewsType="Local"}
1 Object { NewsType="Int"}

var InternationalNewsfound  = $.inArray("Int", NewsTypeArray)  > -1;
```

But 
InternationalNewsfound is shows me false.

Comment: This is because you're comparing an object to a string.

Comment: Use `$.grep()` for checking object properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a filter with jquery **[`.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)**,

```js
var NewsTypeArray = [{"NewsType": "Local"}, {"NewsType": "Int"}];

var InternationalNewsfound = $.grep(NewsTypeArray, function(obj) { 
                                 return obj.NewsType === "Int"; 
                             }).length > 0;
console.log(InternationalNewsfound);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
```

*Note :  While just `.length` would help you check for truthiness you could still use `.length > 0` for the flag.

Answer (score 2):

You're searching an array of objects, but your search value is a string (`"Int")`. `inArray` won't help you here.

ES5's [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) would (and it can be shimmed if you need to support obsolete browsers like IE8):

```js
var NewsTypeArray = [{"NewsType": "Local"}, {"NewsType": "Int"}];

var InternationalNewsfound = NewsTypeArray.some(function(e) {
    return e.NewsType === "Int";
});
console.log(InternationalNewsfound);
```

`Array#some` calls the callback once for each entry in the array. If the callback returns a truthy value, `Array#some` stops and returns `true`. If `Array#some` runs out of entries with the callback never having returned a truthy value, it returns `false`.